# Resize and move floating ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, overlay

I have a floating `ViewGroup` which is made with `WindowManager` and has system overlay permission.
to illustrate it is overlayed on other opened apps...

I want to resize this `ViewGroup` with its children and move it inside, without going out of screen. When I change its size with `setScaleX` and `setScaleY`, the `ViewGroup` actual width and height does not change.

How can I change width and height(scale) and avoid going out of screen limitation with moving(dragging)?

thanks

This is my ViewGroup layout xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/joystick_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#009688"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/_30sdp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/inner_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_30sdp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_joystick_left"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_scale"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_drag_selector"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_delete"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_110sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_125sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_close_selector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here you can see floating ViewGroup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/779wR.png)

Comment: override `onTouch` method from your `ViewGroup` and change `LayoutParams` of `ViewGroup` from it and then update `WindowManager` about it.

Comment: Thanks Jeel, but ViewGroup have 4 children. any Width and height change to parent must apply to children too. how can i do it and keep the ratio?

Comment: In most of cases of default `ViewGroups` like *linear and constraint layouts*, it does scale views if you've `match_parent` or `weights`. But if you still want to scale down something like *if parent is 0.5x scaled down then child also have to be 0.5x* then in such case you'll have to create **Custom ViewGroup** and provide some logic to scale it down.